# Node.js can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: authentication, node.js, http-headers, redis, express

I'm working on a simple node.js project that requires authentication.  I decided to use connect-redis for sessions and a redis-backed database to store user login data.

Here is what I have setup so far:

```
// Module Dependencies

var express = require('express');
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
var crypto = require('crypto');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();  

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'obqc487yusyfcbjgahkwfet73asdlkfyuga9r3a4', store: new RedisStore }));
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

// Message Helper

app.dynamicHelpers({
  // Index Alerts
  indexMessage: function(req){
    var msg = req.sessionStore.indexMessage;
    if (msg) return '<p class="message">' + msg + '</p>';
  },
  // Login Alerts
  loginMessage: function(req){
    var err = req.sessionStore.loginError;
    var msg = req.sessionStore.loginSuccess;
    delete req.sessionStore.loginError;
    delete req.sessionStore.loginSuccess;
    if (err) return '<p class="error">' + err + '</p>';
    if (msg) return '<p class="success">' + msg + '</p>';
  },
  // Register Alerts
  registerMessage: function(req){
    var err = req.sessionStore.registerError;
    var msg = req.sessionStore.registerSuccess;
    delete req.sessionStore.registerError;
    delete req.sessionStore.registerSuccess;
    if (err) return '<p class="error">' + err + '</p>';
    if (msg) return '<p class="success">' + msg + '</p>';
  },
  // Session Access
  sessionStore: function(req, res){
    return req.sessionStore;
  }
});

// Salt Generator

function generateSalt(){
  var text = "";
  var possible= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*"
  for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  return text;
}

// Generate Hash

function hash(msg, key){
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(msg).digest('hex');
}

// Authenticate

function authenticate(username, pass, fn){
  client.get('username:' + username + ':uid', function(err, reply){
    var uid = reply;
    client.get('uid:' + uid + ':pass', function(err, reply){
      var storedPass = reply;
      client.get('uid:' + uid + ':salt', function(err, reply){
        var storedSalt = reply;
        if (uid == null){
          return fn(new Error('cannot find user'));
        }
        if (storedPass == hash(pass, storedSalt)){
          client.get('uid:' + uid + ':name', function(err, reply){
            var name = reply;
            client.get('uid:' + uid + ':username', function(err, reply){
              var username = reply;
              var user = {
                name: name,
                username: username
              }
              return fn(null, user);
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
  fn(new Error('invalid password'));
}

function restrict(req, res, next){
  if (req.sessionStore.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    req.sessionStore.loginError = 'Access denied!';
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
}

function accessLogger(req, res, next) {
  console.log('/restricted accessed by %s', req.sessionStore.user.username);
  next();
}

// Routes

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'TileTabs'
  });
});

app.get('/restricted', restrict, accessLogger, function(req, res){
  res.render('restricted', {
    title: 'Restricted Section'
  });
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.sessionStore.user.username + ' has logged out.');
  req.sessionStore.destroy(function(){
    res.redirect('home');
  });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', {
    title: 'TileTabs Login'
  });
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if (user) {
      req.session.regenerate(function(){
        req.sessionStore.user = user;
        req.sessionStore.indexMessage = 'Authenticated as ' + req.sessionStore.user.name + '.  Click to <a href="/logout">logout</a>. ' + ' You may now access <a href="/restricted">the restricted section</a>.';
        res.redirect('home');
        console.log(req.sessionStore.user.username + ' logged in!');
      });
    } else {
      req.sessionStore.loginError = 'Authentication failed, please check your '
        + ' username and password.';
      res.redirect('back');
    }
  });
});

app.get('/register', function(req, res){
  res.render('register', {
    title: 'TileTabs Register'
  });
});

app.post('/register', function(req, res){
  var name = req.body.name;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var salt = generateSalt();

  client.get('username:' + username + ':uid', function(err, reply){
    if (reply !== null){
      console.log(reply);
      req.sessionStore.registerError = 'Registration failed, ' + username + ' already taken.';
      res.redirect('back');
    }
    else{
      client.incr('global:nextUserId');
      client.get('global:nextUserId', function(err, reply){
        client.set('username:' + username + ':uid', reply);
        client.set('uid:' + reply + ':name', name);
        client.set('uid:' + reply + ':username', username);
        client.set('uid:' + reply + ':salt', salt);
        client.set('uid:' + reply + ':pass', hash(password, salt));
      });

      req.sessionStore.loginSuccess = 'Thanks for registering!  Try logging in!';
      console.log(username + ' has registered!');
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
  });
});

// Only listen on $ node app.js

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(80);
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d", app.address().port);
}
```

Registration works great.  However, upon logging in with the correct user credentials, I am thrown the following error:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I have managed to identify the line that throws this error (`res.redirect('home');`) in `app.post('/login')`.  Just wondering, besides my poorly written code, what I need to do to fix this error.

**UPDATE:**

Versions:

node 0.4.10
express 2.4.3
npm 1.0.22
redis 2.4.0 rc5
connect 1.6.0
connect-redis 1.0.6

Here is the link to my app:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4873115/TileTabs.zip

Comment: You should archive zip your project completely. At least the parts needed for app.js. Right now I am missing Stylus, Jade templates...

Comment: Also which connect, which connect-redis are you using. P.S: your express is already pretty old. After npm update I got => connect@1.6.0, connect-redis@1.0.6, express@2.4.3

Comment: So sorry for the delay.  I updated to express 2.4.3 just now and still the same problem persists.  I also updated the link to a zipped file of my app.  Also, how do I check connect and connect-redis version numbers?

Comment: I assume you have npm installed. Issue `npm ls`

Comment: Definitely.  I got the same versions you did for connect and connect-redis.

Comment: Okay I need to work now, but when I have time I have a look at your archive(zip).

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your persistence.

Comment: @BOSS let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2047/discussion-between-alfred-and-boss)

Comment: fixed problem => authenticate(). See updated answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

The problem was authenticate(). Below I have I think correct implementation:

```
function authenticate(username, pass, fn){
  client.get('username:' + username + ':uid', function (err, reply) {
    var uid = reply;
    client.get('uid:' + uid + ':pass', function(err, reply){
      var storedPass = reply;
      client.get('uid:' + uid + ':salt', function(err, reply){
        var storedSalt = reply;
        if (uid == null){
          fn(new Error('cannot find user'));
          return;
        } else  if (storedPass == hash(pass, storedSalt)) {
          client.get('uid:' + uid + ':name', function(err, reply){
            var name = reply;
            client.get('uid:' + uid + ':username', function(err, reply){
              var username = reply;
              var user = {
                name: name,
                username: username
              }
              fn(null, user);
              return;
            });
          });
        } else {
            return fn(new Error('invalid password'));    
        }
      });
    });
  });
  //return fn(new Error('invalid password'));
}
```

I can't run the example because I don't have your stylus files. Can't you archive your project and post it over here, so that we can also run your code. If my memory serves me right, you could have these problems when you combine old modules with new modules. Which versions of express, connect-redis, redis, connect, etc do you have installed??

P.S: I can not run your code immediately if you upload, because I have to go to bed and have to work in the morning. But hopefully somebody else can help you then. Or maybe it is matter of modules installed.

Comment: Over here?  Do you mean post it on github or something?  Let me check out my versions.

Comment: you could archive it and put it in your Dropbox's public folder for example. Or upload to any upload site like for example mediafire.com

Comment: Updated op, hopefully that'll suffice.

Comment: @Boss that suffices and I solved problem. Authenticate got called multiple times instead of only once!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `req.sessionStore.destroy` is probably sending a "Set-Cookie" header to expire/delete the session cookie and because there's IO involved, node has a chance to send the HTTP response header before your `res.redirect` code runs, and thus the error is generated.  Try just doing your `res.redirect` directly inside `app.post` as opposed to inside the `destroy` callback and see if that avoids the error.

You may also be hitting [this node.js bug](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/752) if code is trying to read headers after they are sent.

Comment: Sadly, that did not fix it.  Although, are you sure you're looking at the right `res.redirect`?  I'm not having trouble logging out, (well, not sure, actually; since I can't login) I'm having trouble logging in.  The `res.redirect` I'm referring to is inside the `app.post('/login')` route.